# Mixed ASP.MVC 3 and Webforms app routing problems on IIS 5.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've got mixed ASP.MVC3/Webform app and I've got problem with deploy on IIS 5.1. I followed this http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2008/11/deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-on-windows-xp-iis.html example and it's working fine for MVC part. Problem is, that Webform page(I need webform for ReportViewer component) cannot be found. Everything is OK in development enviroment (I simply Redirect to "/Report/ReportList.aspx") but not in IIS.

Edit:
So I've found solution by myself. I had `Return Redirect "/Report/ReportList.aspx";` but when I change it to `return  Redirect(Url.Content("~/Report/ReportList.aspx"));`  then it works.

Answer (score 0):

So xxviktor found solution by himself. He had

```
Return Redirect "/Report/ReportList.aspx";
```

but when he changed it to

```
return Redirect(Url.Content("~/Report/ReportList.aspx"));
```

then it works.

Answered as community wiki based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107091/how-to-handle-posts-in-unanswered-lists-containing-self-answers-within-questio) hint.